# C3js and hide dots

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

How can i hide dots in c3js when a point is plotted ? For example in this demo

http://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See below example.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    },
    point: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

Taken from http://c3js.org/samples/point_show.html.